# How to save a loaded model in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm doing a videogame and I have problems of memory, namely I load in my game 8 obj models but I repeat them, so this means that every time I need to add the same model in different position of the map I have done:

```
new THREE.MTLLoader().setPath( './Tree/' ).load( 'untitled.mtl', function ( materials ) {
     materials.preload();
     new THREE.OBJLoader().setMaterials( materials ).setPath( './Tree/' ).load( 'tree.obj', function ( object ) {
        object.scale.set(2, 2, 2);
        object.position.set(10, 0, 30);
        scene.add( object );
     }, undefined, undefined );
});
```

In this way, every time I call this, I istanciate the same object in memory and I need to much memory. Is there any way for saving only one copy in memory and every time I need it I call just this copy?

I have seeked online but I didn't find/understand any solution.

Comment: try https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.clone

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the object multiple times you could clone it via [Object3D.clone()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.clone). However, this is not an ideal solution for your use case since you still have multiple objects in memory and draw each object with a single draw call.

It's better to rendering object like  trees with instanced rendering or to merge the final objects into a single one. In this way, you eventually have a single object in memory and also draw all trees with a single draw call (which is good for performance). Working with both approaches might need some preparation so it's best to study the official examples:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_minecraft (geometries are merged in this example via [BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries))

`three.js R105`